# Customizing WordPress query so that it uses MySQL's optimizer hints

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress

I'd like to do something like this for all WP's queries:

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ * FROM blah blah blah...
```

Is there any example for simple ways to do that?
Maybe by using a hook for WP_Query?

Comment: The `query` hook lets you manipulate the statement in string form, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/

Comment: Be careful! If you have queries that run for more than a second, you're better off doing a root-cause analysis. Just killing them will give a terrible user experience after making them wait, which is double-terrible. Check out John Blackbourn's [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hook for WP_Query. One such hook is pre_get_posts, which allows you to modify the query before it is executed.

Here is an example of how to use the pre_get_posts hook to set the maximum execution time to 1000 seconds:

```
function set_max_execution_time( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 1000 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_max_execution_time' );
```

NB: This code should be added to your functions.php file or a custom plugin. Note that this will only work for queries that use WP_Query, and not for direct SQL queries.